# Dimensions in Eagle Cad

Tags: eaglecad

I'm designing a circuit in Eagle and I need to have fixed dimensions on certain holes. I can of course use the dimension tool to *measure* the distance but I don't see a way to make the dimension "stick" to the hole I'm designing.

Is this possible? So that I can make the dimension tool measure from the hole to the side of the board and then when I move the hole the dimension follows?

[image]

Comment: Its _certainly_ not possible with v6 and earlier. But I suppose you use the latest version anyway?

Comment: I'm using Eagle 9.3.2!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Group tool and move both the hole and the measurement.

Hint: You can use the move command and then select each hole and measurement by holding the Shift key. (Deselect with Control)

Edit:

[image: Select the Hole and the Measurement both with Group]

[image: Drag the hole to the position you like]

I hope I understood it right.
You have to select one side of the measurement only and the hole of course.

Comment: I dont think you understood my question:) I want to be able to move the hole AND make the measurement increase in size while I do so.

Comment: Perfect. I got it after your edit. I have to select only one side. Thank you.